# $3$ independent events $ A, B, C $ what is the $P(AB\cup C)$?

Tags: probability, independence

$A, B, C$ are mutually independent. What is the $P(AB\cup C)$?

My guess

$$P(AB \cup C)=P(AB)+P(C)=P(A)P(B)+P(C) $$
Is this correct or do I have to add some subtraction [$-P(A\cap B \cap C)$]? I guess, I don't have a full understanding of independent events.

Comment: It is not correct because you're assuming C and (A and B) are disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subtract $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ since the term need not be zero.

\begin{align}
P(AB \cup C)&=P(AB)+P(C)-P(ABC)\\&=P(A)P(B)+P(C)-P(A)P(B)P(C)
\end{align}

A particular examples of $A,B,C$ that are mutually independent and are not mutually exclusive are whether you get heads from 3 independent coin tosses.

Comment: yes, thank you. I knew I had to be missing something.